# Moving PolymerElement components around programmatically

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I have been working on a component to streamline a series of other components.  The reason I wanted to do this is pretty much to create 1 place where the implementations would be since the code is the same, we don't have to worry about maintaining 17 html files, just 1.

I was trying to find a way to programmatically move 1 web component into another.  some sort of `A.appendHtml(B);` but i was not 100% sure if that worked with WebComponents.

My goal is to move mine-b's template contents into ele-a before it renders out to the page.  Essentially unwrapping the `mine-b` wrapper and injecting it to where it is suppose to go

```
<template>
  <ele-a></ele-a>
  <div>
    <mine-b></mine-b>
  </div>
</template>
```

`<ele-a></ele-a>` accepts only 2 tag types: `sub-a` and `sub-b`.  `sub-b` can accept `form` tags.

```
<ele-a>
  <sub-a></sub-a>
  <sub-b>
    <form></form>
  </sub-b>
</ele-b>
```

so i thought to myself to create a component which would allow me to streamline all the attribute setting

```
<mine-a>
  <ele-a>
    <content></content>
  </ele-a>
</mine-a>

<mine-b>
  <sub-a></sub-a>
  <sub-b>
    <content></content>
  </sub-b>
</mine-b>
```

which would allow me to do something like:

```
<mine-a>
  <mine-b>
    <form></form>
  </mine-b>
</mine-a>
```

THe issue i have been having is that since ele-a only accepts sub-a and sub-b so i cant define it as a child of ele-a.  The reason is the select attribute inside of ele-a which will prevent me from stamping out mine-b.  So i tried to make it a sibling:

```
<mine-a>
  <ele-a></ele-a>
  <mine-b></mine-b>
</mine>
```

So this is where i am right now.  In the dart for `mine-a` which extends PolymerElement.  Is there a way to move the stamped out contents of the template of `mine-b` to `ele-a`?  IE:  the sub-a, and sub-b?

I was thinking to do something like:

```
<mine-a>
  <ele-a id="targetEle"></ele-a>
  <div id="sourceEle" hidden>
    <content select="mine-b"></content>
  </div>
</mine-a>

class MyElementA extends PolymerElement {
  DivElement get _source => $['sourceEle'];
  ElementA get _target => $['targetEle'];
  MyElementA.created() :  super.created(){
    _target.appendHtml(_source.children());
  }
}
```

or something to just move 1 WebComponent into another?  I have been having some issues with this.

When looking at the PolymerLife Cycle, I was thinking I might be able to do it prior to the dom being initialized, by doing it in the `created` function.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a minimal project reproducing the problem ?

Comment: for the time being, i circumvented functionality to get a simpler approach working which was far from what i wanted to do.  Lateral teams said they are looking to rewrite `ele-a` to be able to allow it to work more dynamically.  Im going to close this because the reason was primarily that a lateral team made a not-so-good control and its underlying code is the limiting factor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a static required control outside of my control, due to team implementation